# Install Intel onboard graphic driver in Asus K53SV?

Tags: drivers, intel-graphics, asus

From the first time installing Ubuntu, I can not enable desktop effects. My laptop is Asus K53SV core i7 SB with hybrid graphic card Intel HD 3000/ Nvidia 540 GM. After installing Bumblebee, I still can't enable it.
I've found these links:
http://intellinuxgraphics.org/download.html
and
http://intellinuxgraphics.org/2011Q1.html
which said "This release has been validated on following hardware: Sandy Bridge HD Graphics 3000 Core i7 2630QM"
How could I reinstall Intel onboard driver this way? I need details. If there is another, how to do that?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Also do you mean the Compiz effects? To help you we need more details of your problem. Do you think you need the driver just because desktop effects won't work? Or is it because of other reasons? Because if you are simply having trouble using desktop effects, it could be unrelated to the Intel graphics driver.

Answer (score 1):

Intel HD 3000 drivers come with Ubuntu 11.04, because they are opensource. If you aren't using 11.04, the best way is upgrading to 11.04.